# Receiving an object derived from an abstract class as a parameter in method

Tags: java, abstract-class

I'm new to Java and I am currently learning about Abstract classes. Currently I am creating a simple RPG. Suppose I have an abstract class called `Person`, which extends  to two other classes, `Warrior` and `Wizard`.

Now suppose that I have another abstract class called `Weapon` where from there we can create different types of weapons(swords, axes, bows etc..) which share some basic methods,  that can be overwritten by other inherited classes, such as `attack()` or `maintenance()`.

When a `Person`(`Wizard` or `Warrior`) will call the `attack()` method at some point in the game, I need to know who will be the attacker and who the defender (show I can modify their life bar status, durability of their weapons , etc) .

(Which essentially means, receiving two objects in the `attack()` method as  parameters).

So here is where I am stuck. The combination of attacker-defender could be `Wizard-Warrior`, `Wizard-Wizard, Warrior-Wizard or Warrior-Warrior`.

How should I implement the `attack()` method in the `Weapon` class so it can permit me to receive an object as a parameter, without caring if the object is going to be wizard or warrior ? Could this be possible?

doing something like this for example?

```
void attack(Person attacker, Person defender)
{
    // add method logic here

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Guns don't kill people, people do" ...so I think it would be more natural to have the attack method in the Person class: void attack(Person target, Weapon weapon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step, derive `Wizard` and `Warrior` from `Person` (you may consider making Person an interface).

Second step, implement `attack(Person attacker, Person defender)` in terms of Person, not in terms of Warior or Wizard. All methohds common to Warrior and Wizard should be available to person. Any method not common should be made irrelevant to `attack()`.

For example, if Wizard has `castBestSpell(Person target)` method, while Warrior has `hitWithWeapon(Person target)`, you need to reduce both methods to `Person.attack(Person target)`. Wizard and warrior will implement `attack(Person target)` differently: one by calling `castBestSpell`, one by calling `hitWithWeapon`.

Answer (score 2):

Not really answering the question, but why not move `attack` to the `Person` class, then you could write it out like

```
class Person
    public void attack(Person target, int damage) {
        target.setLife(life - damage);
        // or target.damage(damage), or however else you want to implement that
        ...
    }
```

then

```
myWarrior.attack(evilWizard, myWeapon.getDamage);
```

That just seems to make more sense to me, since the `Person` will be doing the attacking.

Comment: From a programming standpoint, if there are many types of weapons and different logic will need to be written for each weapon type, then you want the method in the `Weapon` class to take advantage of polymorphism.  Perhaps the method name should be changed to make it look more grammatically correct.

Answer (score 0):

it's easy, Wizard and Warrior need to extend Person

public class Warrior extends Person {
}

It's easy.

Then you can check what it is...

if (attacker instanceof Warrior) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose a different alternative:

You have stated the `attack` method is on the `Weapon` class, however it seems the more logical place for this method would be in the `Person` class. If we think about it in concrete terms, it is not the weapon that is attacking the opponent, it is the `Person`, who is using the weapon, that is attacking.

It is difficult to give a concrete answer without seeing design of the game, however I will assume that your `Person` maintains a `target` field, pointing to whomever is being targeted by this `Person` object.

Additionally, when a player is attacked, they will no doubt "defend" themselves in some fashion (this could be simply in the form of mitigated damage due to armour, or some active ability or action, for example).

So your class will look something like this:

```
public abstract class Person {
    private Person target;
    private Weapon weapon;


    public void attack(){
        target.defend(calculateRawDamage());
    }

    private int calculateRawDamage(){
        // calculate weapon damage plus any modifiers, etc.
    }

    public void defend(int rawDamage){
        // calculate actual damage based on damage-mitigation modifiers
    }
}
```

This example makes a number of assumptions about how your game works, however as I said, it is simply an example, and hopefully illustrates a better way to implement game logic that does not reply on knowing the concrete `Person` or `Weapon` types, as each object will behave in their own specialized fashion according to their concrete type due to polymorphism.